# selenium: trying to use selenium Grid for running tests on multiple browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

[image]I am running these 3 tests on Selenium ID,

[image]

but i want to run these tests in parallel on different browsers , for that i am trying to use Selenium Grid and referring this    http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

for that i am using this code

```
                 public class testjava extends SeleneseTestCase {
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "www.yahoo.com/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testTestjava() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
```

}

but i am getting this exception

```
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:47)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:102)
at com.selenium.testjava.setUp(testjava.java:20)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.java:230)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:228)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:223)
at org.junit.internal.runners.OldTestClassRunner.run(OldTestClassRunner.java:35)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DefaultSelenium is for Selenium 1 (RC)-compability. `localhost` is your RC-server (it's the seleniumserver).

But I would recommend you use Selenium 2. Like it says in your link you have to do the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability); //localhost is your hub here
```

This is a simple example, it requests firefox in your grid. you can specify any browser on any platform:

```
capability.setBrowserName(“firefox”); 
capability.setPlatform(“LINUX”);  
capability.setVersion(“3.6”);
```

And you need at least one node that you register to the hub like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.x.0.jar -role wd -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=3.6,platform=LINUX
```

Again it is assumed Selenium hub is running on localhost. I hope this helps as a start. Just ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks , i know its very basic Q , but i couldnt understand where will i write this code : DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();  ?          and secondly  i want to run one of my testcase in firefox but other in chrome ,what will i do for that

Comment: capability.setBrowserName(“firefox”); or capability.setBrowserName(“chrome”); But for chrome you need to start the chromeserver first on the machine where you want to run the test in chrome: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: thanks, but my first question remains there where will i write this code : DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); as i am using selenium IDE, not eclipse..

Comment: Sry, but IDE is a firefox plugin that only works locally in Firefox. You can export the test scripts in any language (for example Java) and execute them in eclipse.

Comment: thanks, just did that , now in eclipse it says : not resolved: import com.thoughtworks.selenium ,  which selenium jar i should put for that?

Comment: put selenium-java-client-driver.jar ,  its giving error    seleniumexception: nullpointerexception

Comment: use this one: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-java-2.19.0.zip&can=2&q=

in general refer to this site for beginning: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/
there are a lot of tutorials and helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7952/discussion-between-junaidp-and-tester)

Comment: Did you read the article about Chromedriver?? I posted it above and did you read how to start the grid? If you have done this the exception won't appear. Once again: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
and how to set up the grid: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2
I don't know how to explain it in more detail to you because everything you need to know to get this running is in these articles. so just read them carefully. step by step. if you don't understand some step, just ask.

Comment: thanks, i just replace chrome to firefox  and now its giving me :  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)

Comment: hey listen. if you don't provide enough information (what have you done so far, where does this exception appear etc.) nobody can help you. I just said, read the links I posted and you just say change chrome to firefox. so what? did you read them or not? Just follow the steps described there. If you have problems with understanding (maybe you are not a developer, I don't know) then try to get some assistance. This seems to me like there are some basic understandings which are missing (configure classpath etc).

Comment: yeah i am reading this link, what ever i did is according to the link you provided, if you see my code in my question above.yeah may be there is some classpath configuration issue, i have these 3 jars in my classpath , junit-4.0,selenium-java-2.19.0,selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0, (in case any of these jars causing this error)

Comment: There is also a directory called "lib" which is in the download zip file of the link I posted above. this one: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-java-2.19.0.zip&can=2&q=

of course the content of the libs also has to be on the classpath...

Comment: thanks , but it didn't work, same error , i have attached the screenshot of my classpath above

Comment: again, provide information. stacktrace etc. I don't know why you get this exception, I even don't know where you get this exception. It still seems to me that you didn't set up everything as described in the links.

Comment: added stack trace in my question

Comment: SeleneseTestCase is deprecated. Also don't use Selenium 1 as there is no support and new releases. Selenium 2 is the new standard.

Comment: can u guide me how to resolve SeleneseTestCase deprecated issue.

Comment: thanks a lot  , its working fine now,i didnt realize u just said depreceated :), so my 1 testcase is running now,and if i want to run another test case at the same time in my second mozilla ,would it be possible .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JUnit 4 in combination with Selenium.

Copy your JUnit 4 Selenium test into Eclipse.

Write the start up of the Firefox Profile and furthermore `DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();` 
into `@Before`

Start the Hub, start the Node, run your tests.

But I suggest you read the basic tutorials about JUnit 4 and Selenium Testing in JUnit 4.
Just Google to find your solution.

Java knowledge also helps.